# How to preserve the name of an object as list after passing a function through lapply

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following data function:

```r
myfunc <- function(ncluster_no = NULL) {
  set.seed(1)
  # ncluster_no <- "Cluster1"
  df <- mtcars[sample(10)[1:3], ]
  my_list <- list(foo = df)
  names(my_list) <- ncluster_no
  my_list
}

myfunc(ncluster_no = "Cluster1")
```

That produces this named object (dataframe)

```
#> $Cluster1
#>                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#> Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#> Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#> Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

When I use that function in `lapply`:

```
clusters <- c(
  "Cluster_1",
  "Cluster_2")

list_out <- lapply(clusters, myfunc)
```

I get this result:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$Cluster_1
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2


[[2]]
[[2]]$Cluster_2
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

What I want to get is simple naming:

```
$Cluster_1
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2


$Cluster_2
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
```

How can I achieve that? Or is there anything I should modify in `myfunc`?

Comment: Try `sapply(clusters, myfunc, simplify=FALSE)` or `setNames(lapply(clusters, myfunc), clusters)`.

Comment: @r2evans No, it doesn't work. It gives me `$Cluster_1
$Cluster_1$Cluster_1` instead.

Comment: What is wrong with the current version?  You may easily access any element of the output list using the names you expect.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I will pass this list to another external 3rd party function, that strictly required those structure.

Comment: Ok, I see now, sorry for the confusion. It seems as if your "strictly required" structure will preclude you from getting the representation you want on the console.

Comment: Are you allowed to change `myfunc` function ?

Comment: @RonakShah yes. Change in the object type of return value is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sapply` with `simplify = F`, and don't return a named list in your function if you don't want `Cluster_1$Cluster_1`:

```r
myfunc <- function(ncluster_no = NULL) {
    set.seed(1)
    df <- mtcars[sample(10)[1:3], ]
    df
}

clusters <- c("Cluster_1", "Cluster_2")

sapply(clusters, myfunc, simplify = F)
```

Which will return:

```r
$Cluster_1
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Duster 360     14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4

$Cluster_2
                mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Merc 230       22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2
Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Duster 360     14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4
```

The most important thing here is that the function returns a dataframe instead of a named list containing a dataframe. If you do that then you can also use `l <- setNames(lapply(1:2, myfunc), clusters)`, or some other method (see Ronak Shah's suggestion in the comments below regarding `replicate`, etc.), and the results will be the same because the names in `clusters` don't really play a roll in the workings of the function.

Comment: Now, I am thinking why do we want to pass names at all? Using your `myfunc`, we can do `setNames(replicate(2, myfunc(), simplify = FALSE), clusters)` Or `setNames(sapply(1:2, myfunc, simplify = FALSE), clusters)` or `setNames(lapply(1:2, myfunc), clusters)` will also work.

Comment: @RonakShah my thoughts, too. The names serve no purpose within the function. I've added a blurb at the bottom to highlight that fact.